# mongoose.connect error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have a node/express/mongoose app built in typescript. However i am having an issue with mongoose.

I get the following error `TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.` error when using mongoose.

**app.ts**

```
import express from 'express';
import logger from 'morgan';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import passport from 'passport';
import cors from "cors";

import Routes from './routes';
import Config from './config/config';

class App {

    public app: express.Application;
    public config: any;

    constructor() {

        this.app = express();

        this.environment();
        this.database();
        this.middleware();
        this.routes();

    }

    private environment(): void {

        this.config = new Config();

    }

    private database(): void {

        const uri: string = this.config.db.uri;
        const options: any = this.config.db.options;

            mongoose.connect(uri, options).then(

                () => {
                    console.log("MongoDB Successfully Connected On: " + this.config.db.uri)
                },
                (err: any) => {
                    console.error("MongoDB Error:", err);
                    console.log('%s MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running.');
                    process.exit();
                }

            );

    }

    private middleware(): void {

        this.app.use(cors());
        this.app.use(logger('dev'));
        this.app.use(express.json());
        this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
        this.app.use(passport.initialize());

    }

    private routes(): void {

        const routes = new Routes(this.app);

    }

}

export default App;
```

How do i properly handle this?

**EDIT**

Posted the entire app file to give more context. The error specifically points out the following line `mongoose.connect(uri, options)`

> src/app.ts:39:13 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
>
> 39             mongoose.connect(uri, options).then(
>                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: On what line are you getting the error ?

Comment: first it highlights all of this `mongoose.connect(uri, options)`

Comment: Any ideas @titian-cernicova-dragomir

Comment: Not really enough info for ideas something may be null and the compiler is telling you to check for it before you use that something. But without a minimal example that reproduces the error , or more complete definitions it's hard tp say

Comment: Ive updated my question with the full code if you could take a look i would appreciate that. @titian-cernicova-dragomir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of the `connect` function:

```
export function connect(uris: string, options: ConnectionOptions, callback: (err: mongodb.MongoError) => void): null;
export function connect(uris: string, callback: (err: mongodb.MongoError) => void): null;
export function connect(uris: string, options?: ConnectionOptions): Promise<Mongoose>;
```

The only overload to return a `Promise` is the last one, the others explicitly return `null`. Since `options` in your code is typed as `any`, the second parameter can match any of the last two overloads, and since the first match is the one that returns null the compiler selects that one that accepts a callback and returns null.

The simplest solution is to cast `options` to `mongoose.ConnectionOptions` or to type `options` as `mongoose.ConnectionOptions` to begin with:

```
mongoose.connect(uri, options as mongoose.ConnectionOptions).then( … )
```

Comment: genius, ty :) it worked `const options: mongoose.ConnectionOptions`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `mongoose.connect()` could return `null`, and your TypeScript is configured for strict nullness checks (which is a good thing!), so you'll need to "swear" that it's not null by adding an exclamation mark:

```
mongoose.connect(uri, options)!.then(...
```

However, if the return value *does* happen to be `null`, this will crash at runtime.